# Is there a sequence of i.i.d. random variables that is eventually monotonically decreasing?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables

Here is the problem I'm struggling with:

> Let $(X_n)$ be is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables. What is the probability that the sequence is monotonically decreasing from some point on?

First of all, I don't understand what is meant by "probability" in this context. I hope it's not just a weird way to pose an existence/non-existence question.

EDIT: As Michael Greinecker pointed out in the comments, one should show that $$P\{\omega:\forall k \ \ \exists n,m>k \ (n<m \ \text{and} \ X_n(\omega)\leq X_m(\omega))\}=1$$

Would it be a good idea to define something like

$$\lambda_s:= P\{\omega:\forall k \in \{1, \dots,s \} \ \ \exists n,m>k \ (n<m \ \text{and} \ X_n(\omega)\leq X_m(\omega))\}$$

Find $\lambda_s$ (how?) and then take a limit. Does it bring me closer to the solution?

Comment: What is the length of the sequence? If it is infinite, the probability will usually be $0$.

Comment: @Ragnar: the sequence is infinite. So I guess, one needs to show something like $$ \forall k \ \ \exists n,m>k \ \ \forall \omega \in \Omega \ \ (n<m \ \text{and} \ X_n(\omega)<X_m(\omega)) $$
Any hint for such $n,m$?

Comment: You should rather try showing $P\{\omega\in\Omega:\forall k \exists n,m>k(n<m \ \text{and} \ X_n(\omega)\leq X_m(\omega))\}=1$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I must be missing something since I don't really see how "showing that statement $A$ is true" is different from showing that $P\{\omega\in\Omega \ | \ A\}=1$ and how it brings us further. Could you please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: @mathusiast In one case you are showing it for *all* $\omega\in\Omega$, in the other case, you show it for all $\omega\in\Omega$ with the exception of a set of $\omega$'s that has probability zero.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: But if I'd be able to show it for _all_, why would I need to show it for _all except some_? It looks like I'm unfamiliar with the technique you're talking about. I'd very much appreciate if you'd write it up as an answer when you have time. It's not a homework so even if it's next week or so.

Comment: @mathusiast Because you will not be able to show it for all. Suppose all random variables are iid with uniform distribution over $[0,1]$. Then it is not impossible that you get the sample sequence $1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...$. The probability of it happening is zero, but it is not impossible.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I see. Yet it's still a mystery to me how to show that the exception set has probability zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the process is i.i.d., the probability of $E_n=[X_{n+1}\geq X_n]$ does not depend on $n$. If the probability would be zero, we would have $X_n>X_{n+1}$ almost surely. Since the $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are independently and identically distributed, we would get by symmetry that $X_n< X_{n+1}$ almost surely, which is absurd.

The family $(E_{2n})$ is independent. If infinitely many of the events occur, the sequence will not be eventually strictly decreasing. Now $\sum_n P(E_{2n})=\infty$, so by the [second Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result), the probability that infinitely many of the events  $(E_{2n})$ occur is $1$. So the probability that the sequence is eventually strictly decreasing is $0$.

It can be the case that the sequence is eventually nonincreasing, but this happens if and only if the $X_n$ are almost surely constant, by an argument similar to this one.